# How to keep the selected node highlighted when the JTree structure changed

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have built a JTree which dynamically add and remove nodes. I have two buttons which allow the selected node move up and down. The function works correctly but once it's moved one level up, then the selection of that node disappears. I want the user to click the button several times to get the node to the position where he wants it to be.So that please let me know how to set the node selection.

Below is my code.

```
    public void moveTestCaseUp() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = 
            (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getTcBuilderTree().getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    if (selectedNode != null) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = 
                (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selectedNode.getParent();
        if (parentNode != null) {
            int selectedNodeIndex = selectedNode.getParent().getIndex(selectedNode);
            if (selectedNodeIndex > 0) {
                DefaultTreeModel treeModel = 
                        (DefaultTreeModel) getTcBuilderTree().getModel();
                treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(selectedNode);
                treeModel.insertNodeInto(selectedNode, 
                        parentNode, selectedNodeIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you re-select it after every movement?

Comment: Also: please split long lines (>70 chars) so that no horizontal scrolling is required to read you code. This makes it easier to read, and therefore increases the likelihood that people will bother to answer your question.

Comment: I want to make the app more user friendly. Assume there are more than ten nodes and you want to move the last  node to index 2 then it's not good to let the user click the arrow button on and on to get it positioned.

Comment: That is a different question. Your original question was how to keep the selected nodes selected after changing the topology.